# Xamarin AdMob Android c# app crash

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, admob

I tired integrating admob in my xamarin App. But my app Crashes when ever launched.
googleplayservices-ads-29.0.0.2

Image contains code for AndroidManifest.xml

[image]

Below is the code from MainActivity.cs

```
      try
        {

            AdView adView = FindViewById<AdView>(Resource.Id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            adView.LoadAd(adRequest);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string a = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Main.axml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout                                         
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativetry">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativetry1" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:popupBackground="#1976D2" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
            android:popupBackground="#1976D2"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXXXX" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header" />
```

My app is crashing at "adView.LoadAd(adRequest);". need help

Error:

The app dosn't enter in catchblock

```
10-12 12:04:30.776 D/Mono    ( 2370): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
10-12 12:04:30.776 D/Mono    ( 2370): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
10-12 12:04:30.776 D/Mono    ( 2370): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
10-12 12:04:30.776 D/Mono    ( 2370): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
10-12 12:04:30.852 D/Mono    ( 2370): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
10-12 12:04:30.852 D/Mono    ( 2370): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
10-12 12:04:30.852 D/Mono    ( 2370): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
10-12 12:04:30.852 D/Mono    ( 2370): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
10-12 12:04:30.899 D/Mono    ( 2370): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
10-12 12:04:30.899 D/Mono    ( 2370): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
10-12 12:04:30.899 D/Mono    ( 2370): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
10-12 12:04:30.899 D/Mono    ( 2370): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
10-12 12:04:30.910 D/Mono    ( 2370): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
10-12 12:04:30.910 D/Mono    ( 2370): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'.
10-12 12:04:30.910 D/Mono    ( 2370): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'.
10-12 12:04:30.910 D/Mono    ( 2370): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'.
10-12 12:04:30.941 D/Mono    ( 2370): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
10-12 12:04:30.941 D/Mono    ( 2370): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
10-12 12:04:30.941 D/Mono    ( 2370): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
10-12 12:04:30.941 D/Mono    ( 2370): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
10-12 12:04:39.140 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2370): Google Play services is missing.
10-12 12:04:39.227 W/System  ( 2370): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86_64
10-12 12:04:39.232 I/WebViewFactory( 2370): Loading com.android.webview version 52.0.2743.100 (code 275610060)
10-12 12:04:39.305 I/cr_LibraryLoader( 2370): Time to load native libraries: 18 ms (timestamps 437-455)
10-12 12:04:39.305 I/cr_LibraryLoader( 2370): Expected native library version number "52.0.2743.100", actual native library version number "52.0.2743.100"
10-12 12:04:39.373 V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider( 2370): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {43f9eef}
10-12 12:04:39.373 I/cr_LibraryLoader( 2370): Expected native library version number "52.0.2743.100", actual native library version number "52.0.2743.100"
[INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(143)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
10-12 12:04:39.407 I/chromium( 2370): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(143)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
10-12 12:04:39.445 I/cr_BrowserStartup( 2370): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
[FATAL:gpu_info_collector_android.cc(193)] failed to create a pbuffer surface for fetching driver strings. EGL_SUCCESS (3000)
10-12 12:04:39.599 F/chromium( 2370): [FATAL:gpu_info_collector_android.cc(193)] failed to create a pbuffer surface for fetching driver strings. EGL_SUCCESS (3000)
10-12 12:04:39.720 W/google-breakpad( 2370): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
10-12 12:04:39.720 W/google-breakpad( 2370): Chrome build fingerprint:
10-12 12:04:39.720 W/google-breakpad( 2370): 1.0
10-12 12:04:39.720 W/google-breakpad( 2370): 1
10-12 12:04:39.720 W/google-breakpad( 2370): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
10-12 12:04:39.720 F/libc    ( 2370): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2370 (VUPa.VUPa)
```

[Emulator Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWquS.png)

Comment: post the error.

Comment: show the errors please.

Comment: add the exception/stacktrace to your question

Comment: Error has been added

Comment: @JohnJoe I have added the error :)

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I have added the error :)

Comment: @SushiHangover I have added the error :)

Comment: @VibhavPatil Does this emulator not have Google Play Services installed? Try it on a physical device

Comment: @SushiHangover Ill try and let you know soon

Comment: @SushiHangover It worked Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2370): Google Play services is missing.

You need to either use a physical device that has the Play Store and its related services installed, or an emulator that has those installed.

Google is now supplying emulator images that contain the Play APIs, at least for the latest Android versions. In your Android SDK Platform options, you can install emulator images marked "Google **Play** .....".

[image]

These emulators install the full suite of Google Play, Apps and services vs. the ones named "Google **APIs** ...." that only contain an ASOP version of the Android OS.